# ReportViewer problem in google chrome

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, reportviewer

I am using Reportviewer in my asp.net mvc (C#) application. In IE and Firefox, the reportviewer looks fine.

But in Chrome, the header and body gets shrinked. I was able to correct the header display problem as suggested in http://www.mazsoft.com/blog/post/2009/08/13/ReportViewer-control-toolbar-in-Google-Chrome-browser.aspx.

```
  if ($.browser.safari) {
      $("#ReportViewerControl table").each(function(i, item) {
         $(item).css('display', 'inline-block');
      });
  }
```

But the Body(Viewer) part still appears to be in half of the screen. The problem appears to be with the width of empty second `td` of the table:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td onpropertychange="ShowFixedHeaders()" id="oReportCell">....Some Data...</td>
      <td height="0" width="100%"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The Second td in the above table is empty with 100% width, this may be the cause of the bug in chrome. How can i remove the width of the second td or is there any fix for this?
[ReportViewer Design http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/13114a4f00.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/13114a4f00.png)

How can i access the element inside nested iframe?

Comment: The actual problem may be the ReportViewer has nested iframes. its not able to find the "oReportCell" using jquery. I have updated my question with the image where i highlighted the cells that i need to access

Answer (score 6):

If the Reportviewer does not display the data or it is not rendered in any browser then just do the following in your ASP.NET page:

Replace:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

with the following tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

Comment: @AndrewBarber: In future, I'll never try this types of things. And thanks for edited.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and fixed it with jQuery.  Because the report viewer uses iframes, it's not easy getting to the `<TD>` element needing to be removed.  I tried various methods and finally settled on the following hack.  It probably isn't as good as it can be, but it works for me.

First I wrap the report viewer in a `<DIV>` and hide it:

```
<div id="rpt-container" style="display: none;">
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rptViewer" Width="99.9%"    BackColor="#eeeeee" 
            runat="server" ShowExportControls="False"> 
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
 </div>
```

Then I added the following jQuery snippet to locate the  element to be removed allowing successful rendering in Chrome.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $().ready(function() {
         setTimeout( function(){  
             $('td#oReportCell', window.parent.frames[0].frames[1].document).next().remove();  
             $("#rpt-container").fadeIn();
          }, 300);  //slight delay to allow the iframe to load
     });
 </script>
```

I tried using the frameReady plugin, but didn't have much luck. So as a compromise, I simply set a delay of around 300 milliseconds before trying to pick off the DOM element inside the iframe.  If you don't hide/fadeIn the report, you see some ugly animation as the element is removed.

Answer (score 2):

I have similar problem with ReportViewer on my aspx page. In IE9 I have also all fields in the report shrunk because the last TD element in table has `width=100%`.

In my Aspx page, I use

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

When I delete this DOCTYPE element, then fields in report are not shrunk.

Answer (score 1):

Try with more jQuery maybe

```
$().ready(function() {
    $('#ReportViewerControl table td[width="100%"]').attr('width','');
});
```

Although this will probably affect other items in the report?