# How to deal with SSRS reports on mobile phones

Tags: android, reporting-services, pie-chart, ssrs-2008-r2, tablet-pc

I have few SSRS reports (with charts, gauges etc) deployed to the server and they all work fine but not so well when viewed as well worked upon on cell phones/tablets. 
The users find difficult to choose the report parameters, selecting from drop downs and also presentation of data through charts, gauges etc.

I am thinking to modify the SSRS report for cell phones but not sure how to progress. I have searched and started reading some blogs but thought of asking suggestions of experts here who may already dealt this.

I have sample RDL files (deployed to the report server) that I can post here but they are any other typical SSRS Reports with various parameters, charts, gauges etc.

Many thanks.

Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Looking for an solution for the same problem, I have found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12280775/3424212). I have applied it ant it worked!

My context is:
I'm using the ReportViewer Webform component:
Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91

It tested in Androind Asus Zenphone 2. Using the default browser and Chrome.
It worked at desktop chrome  too.

The code change:

> Replace:
>
> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
> ```
>
> with the following tag:
>
> ```
> <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
> ```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12198034)

Comment: Thank you for you advice. Make much more sense!

I have shared the code.

Answer (score 0):

Are the reports being delivered using Report Manager, SharePoint or a ReportViewer control in a web page?

You're using SQL Server 2008 R2, so [the only supported browsers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms156511%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) are Internet Explorer, Firefox and Safari and although it doesn't explicitly state it this almost certainly refers to the desktop versions of these browsers so there's no guarantee that mobile versions will work the same way.

So the SSRS technology you are using is not designed with modern day mobile devices in mind. That said you can still try to make this work: You need to ensure the users are using either Firefox (on Android) or Safari (on iOS). Note that Chrome (or related browsers) are not supported at all. You need to consider how the report security is going to work (e.g. only Basic authentication is supported with Safari).

In terms of layout and report components, you'll have to do some trial and error testing to see what works - and remember it may not work on all devices. You might want to consider providing links to render the reports as PDF files, which have much better support on most devices. There is a great blog post by Adam Aspin on some layout techniques for reports on mobile devices here: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/reporting-services/mobile-bi-with-sql-server-reporting-services/

Generally though, if you're trying to design a solution for mobile devices you really want to consider an upgrade to a more recent version of SQL Server which has support for more browsers (including Chrome) and security options.

Comment: About the ReportViewer Webform component, Have you tried the answer below?
http://stackoverflow.com/a/12280775/3424212